A clarification request regarding rejected edit suggestion
I suggested this edit removing commentary and relevant information from the given link. However this suggestion was rejected.
The text "best" followed by user's name is just a noise and can be removed according to this meta. 
Second edit was to add relevant part of the link. It is always advised to add a relevant information information from that link in case it becomes invalid in future. There is even a delete reason in the popup that appears when you hit delete button in LQP review queue.
The reason for rejection was as follows.

This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

This reason is kinda ambiguous and doesn't really work in this case.
Though, I don't have any issue regarding this matter, but I would like to get a proper explanation for rejected edit suggestion so it can be helpful in future.

I am very sorry for the inconvenience, this was my mistake.
I misunderstood the intention of the edit. I would have approved the removal of the 'Best, X' part but it appeared as though someone had added their answer to the post. After looking at the link again I understand the context. 
If you would like to make the same edit suggestion again, I will make sure it gets approved immediately. 

No problem. :) Thanks for the clarification.
